# Using more than one UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I decided to use a UIPickerView to simulate a kind of dropdown menu.
My problem is, that i want to use more than one UIPickerView.
How do i manage to set up a second UIPickerView?
Adding a new UIViewController? or how does it work?
Adding a second span won't be enough, i need up to 3 more UIPickerViews.
Thanks in advance :)

Code:

```
   -(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
        return 1;
    }

    -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
        return [pickerarray count];
    }

    -(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
        return [pickerarray objectAtIndex:row];
    }

    -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    }

- (void)viewDidLoad {

pickerarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[pickerarray addObject:@"Hamburg"];
[pickerarray addObject:@"Berlin"];
[pickerarray addObject:@"München"];
[pickerarray addObject:@"Bonn"];

pickerarray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[pickerarray2 addObject:@"Hambburg"];
[pickerarray2 addObject:@"Berelin"];
[pickerarray2 addObject:@"Müneechen"];
[pickerarray2 addObject:@"Boneen"];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add all of them into your view.
2. Set them as hidden.
3. Set unique tags for each of them.
4. Add buttons that "reveal them".
5. Implement delegate methods that manage values depending on picker view tag.

**Code update:**

```
// put this before view controllers @implementation
enum {
  MyFirstPickerViewTag = 1,
  MySecondPickerViewTag
} MyPickerViewTags; // fix for warning

// assign tags 1 and 2 respectively to your picker views in IB
// here's one of delegate methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView {
    switch(pickerView.tag) {
        case MyFirstPickerViewTag: {
            return 2;
        }
        case MySecondPickerViewTag: {
            return 3;
        }
    }
    return 1; //  component by default
}
```

Comment: hum i added two of them in my view (ib), they are hidden (calling if clauses to setHidden:NO), going to try to call them seperately, but i'm wondering, how these delegate methods have to look like. edit: is it right to set up their name via IB Identity?

Comment: Setup their tags, not names, via IB. AFAIK names won't matter in your code.

Comment: ah now i got it, but how do i adress tags? 1st picker has tag1, second picker has tag2, i guess i need two mutable arrays, showing different content. DO i have to change the content of these methods? -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

Comment: ah these brackets are closed in my code, don't worry, just failed to copy them in here. Should be okay now. each picker has its own property/action/outlet, i tried to call the different picker in this way

Comment: enum {
 MyFirstPickerViewTag = 1,
 MySecondPickerViewTag = 2,
}

@implementation testViewController


@synthesize // now it looks like this, but i get a warning: No type or storage class may be specified here before 'implementation'

Comment: I have updated my code (added name for the enum after the declaration of tags. No need for `= 2` for second tag.